# Here I have an HTML form and PHP MySQL table, after entering values in the table and after pressing submit button no output appears

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Here I have an HTML form and PHP MySQL table, after entering values in the table and after pressing submit button no output appears.

This is my PHP code for creating, inserting and displaying MySQL table:

```
<?php
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $cs=$_POST["cs"];


        $tab="create table stock1 (id INT PRIMARYKEY, Closing_Stock INT)";
        $in="INSERT into stock1 values('$id','$cs')";
        $q="SELECT * FROM stock1";

        $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");


        mysqli_query($con,$tab);
        mySqli_query($con,$in);
        $re=mysqli_query($con,$q)or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($re))


        {
            echo $row[0]."&nbsp &nbsp".$row[1]."&nbsp &nbsp".$row[2]."&nbsp &nbsp".$row[3]."&nbsp &nbsp".$row[4];
        }
    ?>
```

This is my HTML form code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Database</title>

</head>    

<body>   

<form name="form1" action="stk1.php" method="post" >
<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=10 align="center"  width="600" height="200">
<caption><font size=20 font color=black>DETAILS</font></caption>
<tr>
<td>
<font color="white">Id </font> 
</td>
<td>
 <input type="text" name="id"/>
</td></tr><br>
<tr>
<td>
<font color="white">Stock /Opening : </font> 
</td>
<td>
 <input type="text" name="cs" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
 <input type="submit" />
</td>
<td>
 <input type="reset" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comment at line where you have done mistakes and need to improve your code.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$cs = $_POST["cs"];

if (isset($id) && isset($cs)) {// check for input values


   $tab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Closing_Stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";// use TABLE IF NOT EXISTS here

    $in = "INSERT INTO stock1 (id,Closing_Stock) values('$id','$cs')";// forget column name 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM stock1";
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    mysqli_query($con, $tab);
    mysqli_query($con, $in);// check spelling of mysqli
    $re = mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re,MYSQLI_NUM)) {// add MYSQLI_NUM for numeric array
        echo $row[0] . "&nbsp &nbsp" . $row[1];// only two column in your code
    }
}
```

Comment: please copy your create query and paste in phpmyadmin it will show an error mean this create query has an error. avoid this comment if you don't like sorry

Comment: @PRANAV yes you are correct i update my code and thanks for pointing it.

Comment: thank a lot Saty ... it worked

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your create table query

```
$tab="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock1` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `Closing_Stock` int(15) NOT NULL
) ";
```

second at the beginning of the page check whether page submitted or not using

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)> 0){
   //other database operation code goes here
}
```

third after executing query to get records check whether result comes or not using

```
 if($re->num_rows > 0){
 //show row data here
 }
```

four you have only selected two column in query and printing for col in html replace it by

```
 echo $row[0]."&nbsp &nbsp".$row[1]."&nbsp &nbsp";
```

five when executing insert query you have misspelled mysqli method replace with

```
$result=mySqli_query($con,$in);
```